# Three.js raycasting when its not full screen

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js, raycasting

I've been having issues with three.js raycasting recently.

I have a div element for which the element is not the full screen and it should not be the full screen and I think this is causing issues with the positioning of the raycast which I don't know how to fix.

```
    let mouseVector = new THREE.Vector3()
let raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster()

Object.assign(mouseVector, {
  x: 2 * (e.clientX / canvas.width) - 1,
  y: 1 - 2 * (e.clientY / canvas.height)
})

raycaster.setFromCamera(mouseVector, camera)

let intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(scene.children)

for(const intersection of intersects) {
  console.log(intersection)
 }

   mouse.x = ( e.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
   mouse.y = - ( e.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

  raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );    
  intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children, true );
  console.log(intersects);

  for(const ray of intersects) {
    if(ray.object.name !== "Grid") {
      if(smallestDist == undefined){
          smallestDist1 = ray;
        }else if(smallestDist > ray.distance){
          smallestDist1 = ray
        }
    }
  }
   mouse.x = ( e.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = - ( e.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
  raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );    
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );

  for ( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) {
    if(intersects[i].object.name == "Grid"){
    }else{
      if(smallestDist == undefined){
        smallestDist = intersects[i];
      }else if(smallestDist > intersects[i].distance){
        smallestDist = intersects[i]
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(smallestDist1)
  if(smallestDist1){
    const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 0.5, 15, 15 );
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xFF0000} );
    const sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    sphere.position.set(smallestDist1.point.x, smallestDist1.point.y, smallestDist1.point.z)
    sphere.name = "TestSphere"
    scene.add( sphere );
  }
```

Above is the code i've tried however as the element with the 3D object isn't full window sized I think it's bugging out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try to compute `mouse` like so:

```s
const rect = renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();
const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
const y = event.clientY - rect.top;

mouse.x = ( x / canvas.clientWidth ) *  2 - 1;
mouse.y = ( y / canvas.clientHeight) * - 2 + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The top-left point of the browser window is the origin of coordinate `(0, 0)` for MouseEvent, while the exact center point of canvas for threejs.

[Click here to see coordinate details.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiU5G.png)

As shown the image above, four corner points of the canvas is equivalent to `(-1, 1), (1, 1), (1, -1), (-1, -1)` under threejs context.

Otherwise, the canvas might have offsets to the browser `(0, 0)`, which can be accessed with `canvas.offsetTop` and `cavas.offsetLeft`.

With all above considered, any MouseEvent client coordinate `(event.clientX, event.clientY)` should be mapped to threejs coordinate as below:

```js
mouse.x = ( (event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft) / canvas.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = ( (event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop) / canvas.clientHeight ) * -2 + 1;
```